# Add new column by taking column values of existing column having particular value

Tags: python, pandas

for example dataframe look like this,

```
taskname date1

t1        13
t2        12
t3        10
.
.
.
.
t89       56
```

output dataframe should look like,

```
taskname date1 date2

t1        13   
t2        12    12
t2        31    31
t3        15
t1        18
t2        10    10   
.              
.
.
.
t89       56
```

basically I want to copy t2 date1 values to date2 and other spaces in date2 should be left empty

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where) method like this.

```
df['date2'] = df.date1.mask(df.taskname == 't2')
```

Data should look like this:

```
taskname date1 date2
t1        13    NaN
t2        12     12
t2        31     31
t3        15    NaN
t1        18    NaN
t2        10     10   
.              
.
.
.
t89       56    NaN
```